# while viewing PDF file using "WebBrowser.Navigate()" function gives white(blank) page

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, acrobat

**I want to display a PDF file in web browser control present on form using "WebBrowser.Navigate()" function.**

I have Adobe Acrobat Professional 7

If I check "Display PDF in Browser" present under Edit>Preferences in Acrobat and
1) i view any PDF in IE it shows in IE tab and not in a seperate acrobat window.
2) i view the PDF through code using "WebBrowser.Navigate()" function, nothing is displayed in web browser control on form.

If I uncheck "Display PDF in Browser" present under Edit>Preferences in Acrobat and 
1) i view any PDF in IE it doesnt show anything.
2) i view the PDF through code using  "WebBrowser.Navigate()" function, a seperate acrobat window opens the document instead the document opening in Web Browser Control on form.

have googled the issue many times but nothing seems to help me.

Comment: 1 is your OS 64 bit? 2 is your project targeting AnyCPU?

Comment: yes my os is 64 bit. No